# wordpress get recent comments

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have been tryin for the last few hours to research how to get recent comments from wordpress. here is how I managed to get recent posts....

```
    <h4>Recent Posts</h4>
    <ul>
        <?php
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
            $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
            foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
            }
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </ul>
```

how do I get the latest comments..

ps. I have tried to change the posts to comments and doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Steven

Comment: You can use a widget for that (there is one by default in Wordpress): http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-show-recent-comments-in-wordpress-sidebar/

Comment: I know I can but I would rather learn the code ... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve recent comments using `get_comments()`.

`get_comments()` works in a very similar way to the function you're using to retrieve posts.

```
<?php $recent_comments = get_comments( array( 
    'number'      => 5, // number of comments to retrieve.
    'status'      => 'approve', // we only want approved comments.
    'post_status' => 'publish' // limit to published comments.
) );

if ( $recent_comments ) {
    foreach ( (array) $recent_comments as $comment ) {

        // sample output - do something useful here
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment ) ) . '">' . get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . '</a>';

    }
}
```

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments